# deviceQuery fails on CUDA 7.5 installation ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

I installed **CUDA-7.5** with **nvidia-355** drivers but the **deviceQuery** sample failed though the Nvidia-X-Settings control panel shows I have 144 CUDA cores. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: After upgrading to CUDA 7.5 and nvidia-352 (352.39) my Ubuntu 14.04 shows black screen on boot and becomes unresponsive to keyboard actions. I can only access the system from another computer over ssh. The system cannot be restarted or powered off by a command. I have to long-press the power button to forcefully shut down the system.

Comment: Downgrading to CUDA 7.0 and nvidia-346 solves the issue. After the downgrade, the system was unresponsive again during the first boot but worked fine on the second boot. CUDA 7.0 and nvidia-346 are part of a [local package installer](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-70?sid=948655). I am using GeForce GT 520.

Comment: I had that problem. My mouse (and time on the laptop)  froze. I noticed the time issue because i left my computer sitting there for a few minutes.    Goint into `Ctrl-Alt-F1` or `Ctrl-Alt-F2` and then returning to X windows usng `Ctrl-Alt-F7` always fixed the issue temporarily.   Reinstalling my nvidia-355 after installing  CUDA-7.5 mitigated th issue considerably.

Answer (score 1):

In the CUDA documentation, we were advised to use the command `setenforce 0` under SELINUX. That worked once for me (in running CUDA samples).

On other forums, we were advised to work under superuser, via `sudo su` of `sudo COMMAND` and this always worked.

I had another hiccup while compiling the CUDA samples but i corrected it by adding these lines to my `~\.bash_rc`:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-355:${LIBRARY_PATH}
export LIBRARY_PATH
```

We had been advised to use:

```
$ LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-355:${LIBRARY_PATH} make
```

But i don't understand that for now.

Answer (score 0):

mine is okay, but before I upgraded, I followed its' suggestion to uninstalled all the nvidia display driver and CUDA and restored to level 3 (it's weird for Ubuntu), and also removed the blacklist for nouvea, in addition, I also purged all the stuff starting with nvidia*. masked all relevant lib variables in ld.so.conf and ~/.bashrc and updated it. hope this might be help for you.