# deviceQuery for CUDA 7.5 fails without sudo

Tags: nvidia, cuda

If I run `./deviceQuery` without sudo:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 30
-> unknown error
Result = FAIL
```

But running it with sudo (`sudo ./deviceQuery`) works, and after I run it once with sudo, subsequent runs of `./deviceQuery` without sudo also results in pass.

My guess is that the first run with sudo initialises some files correctly which would otherwise cause it to fail. I am not sure how to debug this further, however.

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/672430/devicequery-fails-on-cuda-7-5-installation-ubuntu-14-0-4

Comment: can you share the path in which your CUDA samples are installed?  This usually happens due to permission.

Comment: Hi @pradyot, the path where I am running `./deviceQuery` is `/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery`

Comment: Yea, that's it, to modify or run any file in` /usr` directory you need root privileges. That is why you need to run your executable files with `sudo` . If you install your CUDA samples in home directory, then you need not use `sudo` . Go through [this link](http://askubuntu.com/a/135679/518423)  and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37726/172144), it might help.

Comment: @pradyot, that is strange because after the first run of sudo ./deviceQuery, subsequent runs without sudo can work.

Comment: Well according to [cuda toolkit document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions)`If a CUDA-capable device and the CUDA Driver are installed but deviceQuery reports that no CUDA-capable devices are present, this likely means that the /dev/nvidia* files are missing or have the wrong permissions.`                        so after your first sudo execution all permissions would have set. I am not sure, but do look for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I build i had to do:

```
sudo make -j4
```

Otherwise some errors pop out, then I had same problem.

Change permissions from inside samples folder:

```
sudo chmod 755 -Rf *
sudo chown nobody:nogroup -Rf
```

Hope its not to layman way tho :D